# Horizontal lines on either sides of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Can't figure out a way to have a centered TextView with vertically centered horizontal lines on either sides, stretched to the left and right end of the screen. Like on this picture below.

[image: That's what I'm talking about]

Any insight would help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally came up with this solution that does exactly what is required

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            >

        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_heading_description"
                android:textSize="@dimen/add_headings"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white"
                />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am having problem with the accepted answer, so sharing my way:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/secondary_text"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="@string/Or"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/secondary_text"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am doing it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="#999999" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="DESCRIPTION"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="#999999" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that this is not a perfect answer but may give you an idea.

Here's how its looking :

[Test Image http://imageshack.com/a/img854/9623/exly.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img854/9623/exly.jpg)

Comment: That doesn't center the textview, does it? You need to change 90dp width with every text/font size change to make it look like it's centered?

Comment: True, as I mentioned, this answer is not perfect.. Just a though of achieving those lines. Anything to make it better will be nice too.

Comment: ok, was just checking if I understood you correctly. Would be great to find a way to really center the textview...

Comment: Yes, I think we need to make some tweaks to the layout

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it, and it looks exactly like I wanted.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <View
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="or"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would be an OK solution if you'd want to have something like this in one screen. Imagine if you'd need to have it in 5+ screens. What then? Well suggestions would be: custom layout and use ``<include>`` or creating ``CustomTextView`` with slightly modified ``onDraw(Canvas canvas)`` method. I myself chose #2. Cheers!